# stack size exceeded when passing objects as metadata in winston

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, winston

In ,winston when I tried logging by passing a mongoose query result as a metadata argument, winston just spit out like a thousand lines of log before the task quit.

So for a log like this :

```
tSchool.findById(bus.schoolid,function(err,school){
   winston.info('loaded school',school);
});
```

Here's a small piece of whats get output :

```
return _next.apply(this, arguments);
}, remove=function wrappedPointCut() {
  var args = [].slice.call(arguments);
  var lastArg = args.pop();
  var fn;
  var originalStack = new Error().stack;
  var $results;
  if (lastArg && typeof lastArg !== 'function') {
    args.push(lastArg);
  } else {
    fn = lastArg;
  }
  var promise = new Promise.ES6(function(resolve, reject) {
    args.push(function(error) {
      if (error) {
        // gh-2633: since VersionError is very generic, take the
        // stack trace of the original save() function call rather
        // than the async trace
        if (error instanceof VersionError) {
          error.stack = originalStack;
        }
        _this.$__handleReject(error);
        reject(error);
        return;
      }

      // There may be multiple results and promise libs other than
      // mpromise don't support passing multiple values to `resolve()`
      $results = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
      resolve.apply(promise, $results);
    });

    _this[newName].apply(_this, args);
  });
  if (fn) {
    if (_this.constructor.$wrapCallback) {
      fn = _this.constructor.$wrapCallback(fn);
    }
    return promise.then(
      function() {
        process.nextTick(function() {
          fn.apply(null, [null].concat($results));
        });
      },
      function(error) {
        process.nextTick(function() {
          fn(error);
        });
      });
  }
  return promise;
}
```

So I wanted to know a few things :

1. Why is passing a mongoose query result, which is supposed to be just a small json object, printing such gibberish?
2. Will this happen for other objects also - like the `err` objects in callbacks .etc?
3. How do I prevent this? Checking each and every log statement to ensure no query results are passed is not very practical.

Thanks in advance.

**Update :**

Issues [#862](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston/issues/862), [#474](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston/issues/474) and [#914](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston/issues/914) are tracking/related to this problem, but there hasn't been much progress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been fixed in pull request [#977](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston/pull/977) of Winston. you can check out the details on the PR page.